# Выбор папки для случайного отображения фото

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Имеется код, который выводит изображения из папок.

Как изменить код для выбора только одной папки?

```
<?php
//указываем папки с изображениями
$folder_mas = array('images/river','images/clouds','images/mountains');
$images = array();
//выбираем случайную папку
$folder = $folder_mas[rand(0,2)];
$all_files = scandir($folder);
while ($i++ < sizeof($all_files)){
    //выбираем только изображения с расширением .png, .jpg и .gif
    if (!strstr($all_files[$i],".png") and !strstr($all_files[$i],".jpg") and
    !strstr($all_files[$i],".gif")) continue;
    array_push($images, $all_files[$i]);
}
//перемешиваем массив
shuffle($images);

$img_src = $folder."/".$images[0];
echo '<img src="'.$img_src.'" alt="">';

$img_src = $folder."/".$images[1];
echo '<img src="'.$img_src.'" alt="">';

$img_src = $folder."/".$images[2];
echo '<img src="'.$img_src.'" alt="">';
?>
```

Comment: Ну так `$folder = $folder_mas[rand(0,2)];` и выбирает одну случайную папку из трех.

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете сделать это проще используя `glob`.

```php
<?php
//указываем папки с изображениями
$folder_mas = array('images/river','images/clouds','images/mountains');
$images = array();
//выбираем случайную папку
$folder = $folder_mas[rand(0,2)];
$files1 = glob($folder."/*{img,png,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE); // Получаем только картинки в указанной папке.  уже в массиве
//перемешиваем массив
shuffle($files1);

echo '<img src="'.$files1[0].'" alt="">';
echo '<img src="'.$files1[1].'" alt="">';
echo '<img src="'.$files1[2].'" alt="">';
```

Comment: а как исключить повторения картинок?

Comment: @Dozent Что Вы имеете ввиду? У Вам же в конкретной папке находятся файлы с уникальными именами. Система не позволить Вам создать 2 файла одинаковым именем и расширением. Какая на текущий момент у Вас стоит задача?